# every day Update the age depends on DOB automatically on each row in sql

Tags: sql

I want to update the age of employees present in the database according to Date of birth (Field name is DOB),but it should update automatically after application start.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not just select the age as a calculation in your query?

Comment: Wrong way. Never store calculated ages, calculate when needed! Views are perfect.

Comment: @jarlh its needed to generate report. report is generated according to the age above 50 yers like wise....

Comment: What RDBMS is this? My answer should work for SQL Server and Oracle, but will need small modifications for MySQL. Also, if I know the RDBMS, I can give an actual useful formula for age.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want this field to be a part of your table, rather than in a view, as suggested by @jarlh in the comments. So why not change it into a computed column instead?

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName]
DROP COLUMN [Age];

ALTER TABLE [YourTableName]
ADD [Age] AS ([Your Age Formula]);
```

Comment: MS SQL Server? (Dbms not specified here.)

Comment: @jarlh, yeah, I asked the question above, I'll update if OP tells us which RDBMS he's using.

Answer (score -2):

Use trigger to update the age field and make it run on the midnight of the day

Comment: Actually you mean the Age field

Comment: the query for all rows in the database so row need to be automatically ++ in the loop 
can anyone provide me the solution code

Comment: Triggers are "triggered" by INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. Not possible to start at a specific time. A stored procedure is perhaps what you meant?